# PHP, except date function, is there any function can decode date?

Tags: php, datetime, date

Except for date function, is there any function that can decode date? I think the real date should be in recent days, not a day in 2033.

```
<?php
$date = '1294605921000';
echo  date("m-d-Y H:i:s", $date);
//11-08-2033 23:55:20
?>
```

Comment: First of all, it is not a date by any means. Second, subtract microseconds part from this unusual timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but since that timestamp is likely in milliseconds instead of seconds, divide it by 1000:

```
echo date("m-d-Y H:i:s", floor($date / 1000));
```

Comment: Thanks all, the timestamp is likely in milliseconds instead of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp looks as though it has been generated by JavaScript, which uses milliseconds. If you divide the timestamp by 1000, you get the right date:

```
<?php
$date = 1294605921000/1000;
echo  date("m-d-Y H:i:s", $date);
//01-09-2011 20:45:21
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this is an excel type date serial - but i dont recognise the example you put.

From the Manual http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

```
<?
function xl2timestamp($xl_date)
{
$timestamp = ($xl - 25569) * 86400;
return $timestamp;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
gmdate — Format a GMT/UTC date/time
gmstrftime — Format a GMT/UTC time/date according to locale settings
...
```

Or just take a look here... Old, but good [PHP Manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)